# What is the main difference between useForm() and axios() for form submittion with vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, inertiajs

I want exact difference between useform and axios with example to submit a form.
I want to trying in my project of quiz submission. whenever user choose answer after click on submit button answer will save in database and move to next question. so what can use useForm or axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exact difference between axios and useForm
a) axios is npm package for fetch data and call api
b) useForm is react hook to make data

Comment: can you explain with example